# How do I change the theme of File Picker created using Intent?

Tags: android

What I exactly want to ask is this: How can I change the theme of the **file picker** I created as specified in the codes? Example, File Picker' s actionBar color, background color, status bar color,...  (ie colorPrimary, colorPrimaryVariant,...)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
try {
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a file"), 100);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The **file picker view** (color etc) I get with these codes does not match the colors of my application. This is my problem. I will be glad if you help me. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

> How can I change the theme of the file picker I created as specified in the codes?

That is not supported, sorry.